# Show module Content in theme Development [Prestashop]

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to create a theme using Prestashop 1.6 and the Default theme as reference.

Whenever i try

```
{HOOK_TOP}
```

in my header.tpl , it display the search,cart modules.

But in my case i just want the search module to be displayed.How can i display only the search block and the signIn,create account i want them to be displayed in another place.

Also can i get any advice or tutorials from where i can learn the theming the right way.I guess i am doing stuff the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new hooks for each module you want to display elsewhere.

By default, the blocks you don't want are hooked to TOP.

You need to un-hook those from TOP.
Create new one :
- sql :

```
INSERT INTO ps_hook (name,title,description,position,live_edit) VALUES ('yourNewHook','title of your new hook', 'description of your new hook', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO ps_hook_alias (alias, name) VALUES ('the alias of your new hook','yourNewHook');
```

- controller :

  public function hookYourNewHook ($param) { 
  if (!$this->_prepareHook($param)) 
  return;
  return $this->display(**FILE**, 'templateofyournewhook.tpl');}

Modify or add a register hook in public function install() : `$this->registerHook(' alias of your new hook')`

Now you can call your hook in a tpl with {hook h="yourNewHook"}